# Only see "Off" option on AirPlay Display

Tags: macbook-pro, display, airplay

I have a MacBook Pro and for some reason the AirPlay icon has disappeared from the menu bar. When I go to System Preferences → Displays, the status of AirPlay shows "Off" and there's no way to change it since it doesn't show the "On" option. I have an iPad that is sitting nearby and they are connected to the same WiFi network.

[image: AirPlay Display Off]

Comment: That's a copy-paste of the linked question and a screenshot from my answer on the linked question! In the future, just leave another answer on the existing question rather than re-asking the question to self-answer.